# SpringBoot Web Application : JSP page throws 404 error

Tags: java, maven, jsp, tomcat, spring-boot

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

The above error rendered in my browser while hit a http://localhost:8080

MySpringBoot Start page:

```
@SpringBootApplication 
public class AppStart  { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run (AppStart.class,args);
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
@RequestMapping("/hello/{name}")
public  @ResponseBody ModelAndView hello ( @PathVariable String name){  
    System.out.println("AppStartController:hello ");
    ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
    model.addAttribute("name", name);
    return new ModelAndView("index");   
   }
}
```

my index.jsp has "Hello World" text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the following properties in **application.properties** which is located in **src/main/resources/** resolves this issue and the index page is displayed as expected.

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix:/
spring.mvc.view.suffix:.jsp
```